# The meaning of 'word' in Grep

Tags: regex, linux, grep

In the man page for grep it says that:

```
> The symbols \< and \> respectively match the empty string at the
> beginning and end of a word.
```

What is meant here by word?

**I know that word is defined in -w**, but here is the proof that it has a different meaning in this context:

If file 'test' contains `hi/`,  and I `grep -w 'hi/' test`, I get a match,
but if I `grep 'hi/\>' test`, I don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The beginning of a word is a word character (a letter, number, or underscore) that is not preceded by another word character, and the end of a word is a word character that is not followed by another word character.  A "word" is then just a series of word characters.

The reason `hi/\>` doesn't match `hi/` is because the `\>` is preceded by a non-word character (`/`), and so that can't be the location of an end-of-word.

Comment: This explains almost everything.  The issue is that when I run grep -w 'hi/' test, the entire 3 char sequence is highlighted/matched.  How can this be explained?

Comment: @user3465829: `-w` only checks what's adjacent to the `hi/` in the text; unlike `\<...\>`, it doesn't care about the characters *inside* the match.